# problem with removing student from array creates error

Tags: java

This program is created to store all student details and course details. The problem happens when trying to remove a student from this array it creates a error but only happens if you add a student to the array in option 2 in the program. You are able to remove a student when you haven't added a student it's only when you add a student that the error happens.
Main:

```
package javacoursework;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author zhunt
 */
public class JavaCoursework {
static student[] students;
  static courses[] course;
   
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
      throws FileNotFoundException {
 
        //creating File instance to reference text file in Java
        File text = new File("students.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split(",");
            student.FName.add(split[0]);
            student.SName.add(split[1]);
             student.DOB.add(split[2]);
             student.Address.add(split[3]);
             student.Gender.add(split[4]);
        }
            File course = new File("course.txt");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(course);
            
            while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                String info = scan.nextLine();
                String[] split2 = info.split(",");
                courses.CName.add(split2[0]);
                courses.Lecturer.add(split2[1]);
                courses.Enrolled.add(split2[2]);
              
             
        }      
        
      


       
        Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

        int x;
        //students = new Student[0];
        students = new student[2];
       
        do
        {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println( "Do you want to:"  );
            System.out.println( "\t0) View Students" );
            System.out.println( "\t1) View Students' Details" );
            System.out.println( "\t2) Add a Student" );
            System.out.println( "\t3) Remove a Student" );
            System.out.println( "\t4) View Courses Details" );
            System.out.println( "\t5) Exit Progarm" );
            x = Integer.parseInt(kb.nextLine());


            switch (x) 
            {

            case 0: 
                student.ViewStudents();
                break;
            case 1: 
                student.ViewDetails();
                break;
            case 2:
                student.addStudent();
                break;
            case 3:
                student.removeStudent();
                break;
            case 4: 
                courses.Report();

                break; 

            default: 
            }
        }
        while( x != 5);

    }
    }
```

Student:

```
package javacoursework;


import java.util.Scanner;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author zhunt
 */
public class student {
     // Make 'static' so as to maintain the same 
    // collection throughout all instances of Student.
     public static java.util.List<String> FName = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public static java.util.List<String> SName = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public static java.util.List<String> DOB = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public static java.util.List<String> Address = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public static java.util.List<String> Gender = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    
 

    
   
   public static void addStudent(){     
       if(FName.size()>19){
           System.out.print("The maximum amount of 20 students are currently being stored in the system. If you wish to add a new student you need to remove an existing student from the program");          
       }
       else{
           Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );
           String Fname;
           String Sname;
            String Dob;            
            String address;
            String gender;
            System.out.println( "\tInput Information" );
    System.out.println( "\tFirst Name: ");
            Fname = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tSurname: ");
            Sname = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tDate of Birth(dd-mm-yyyy): ");
            Dob = kb.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println( "\tAddress: ");
            address = kb.nextLine();
    System.out.println( "\tGender(Male/Female): ");
            gender = kb.nextLine();
    if(Fname!=""&&Sname!=""&&Dob!=""&&address!=""&&gender!="")
    {
        if(gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")||gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male")){
            FName.add(Fname);
           SName.add(Sname);
           DOB.add(Dob);
           Address.add(address);
           Gender.add(gender);
           System.out.print(Fname+" "+Sname+" has been added to the system");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Gender must be entered as male/female. Please try again");
        }
         
    }
    else{
        System.out.print("You may not leave out any of the required information. Please try again");
    }
           
          
       }
   }
   public static void ViewDetails()
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

    String i;
    
    System.out.println( "Enter the full name of the student you wish to view: ");
    i = kb.nextLine();
    String[] name = i.split(" ");
    boolean found=false;
    for(int x=0; x <FName.size();x++){
       
        if(FName.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(name[0]))
        {                    
         if(SName.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(name[1]))
            {
                found=true;
                System.out.print("Student found here are the students full details: ");
                System.out.print(FName.get(x)+", "+SName.get(x)+", "+DOB.get(x)+", "+Address.get(x)+", "+Gender.get(x));
            }
        }
    }
    if(found==false)
    {
        System.out.print("Student entered cannot be found.");
    }

   
}
    public static void removeStudent(){
        Scanner kb = new Scanner( System.in );

    String i;
    
    System.out.println( "Enter the full name of the student you wish to remove: ");
    i = kb.nextLine();
    String[] name = i.split(" ");
    boolean found=false;
    for(int x=0; x <FName.size();x++){
       
        if(FName.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(name[0]))
        {                    
         if(SName.get(x).equalsIgnoreCase(name[1]))
            {
                found=true;
                 FName.remove(x);
                 SName.remove(x);
                DOB.remove(x);
                Address.remove(x);
                Gender.remove(x);
                System.out.print(FName.get(x)+" "+SName.get(x)+" has been removed from the course");
            }
        }
    }
    if(found==false)
    {
        System.out.print("Student entered cannot be found. Please try again");
    }  
    }
    public static void ViewStudents(){
     for( int i = 0; i < FName.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(SName.get(i)+", "+FName.get(i));
        }   
    }  
}
```

Course:

```
package javacoursework;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author zhunt
 */
import java.util.Collections;
public class courses {
     // Make 'static' so as to maintain the same 
    // collection throughout all instances of Courses.
    public static java.util.List<String> CName = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public static java.util.List<String> Lecturer = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    public static java.util.List<String> Enrolled = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    
     public static void Report(){
     int enrolled=student.FName.size();
    
     double male=Collections.frequency(student.Gender, "Male");
     male=male+Collections.frequency(student.Gender, "male");
 
     male=(male / enrolled)*100;      
     double female=100-male;
     
     System.out.print("Course: "+CName.get(0)+"\nLecturer: "+Lecturer.get(0)+"\nStudents Enrolled: "+enrolled+"\nPercentage Male: "+String.format("%.2f", male)+"%"+"\nPercentage Female: "+String.format("%.2f", female)+"%");
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 19, Size: 19
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:659)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
    at javacoursework.student.removeStudent(student.java:124)
    at javacoursework.JavaCoursework.main(JavaCoursework.java:84)
C:\Users\xxray\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
```

Comment: and should we assume wht error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In code of `Student#removeStudent`, when the student was found, you're deleting it and then trying to access deleted student by its index.

Consider next case:

1. Students list has 20 elements (last student *Bob* has an index of `x = 19`)
2. We're deleting Bob from the list by calling `FName.remove(x)`
3. Students list now contains only 19 elements
4. We're trying to access the 20th element of the list by calling `System.out.print(FName.get(x)+" "+SName.get(x)+" has been removed from the course")`. And because the list has only 19 elements, we're getting `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. To fix this issue, save removed items into local variables and print them afterwards.

After this two improvement the code will be look like some think like that:

```
fname = FName.remove(x);
sname = SName.remove(x);
DOB.remove(x);
Address.remove(x);
Gender.remove(x);
System.out.print(fname + " " + sname + " has been removed from the course");
```